# Autolayout & Alignment Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

I want to make similar ui for all iPhones & i am currently using auto layout for that, but i do not know how to create this `UI` using `NSLayoutConstraint`?

This UI works fine in small screen but i want same ui for bigger iPhone as well(keep certain amount of space between buttons). how can i add constraint in this to get same ui as iPhone 4s.

i took `UIButton` & below titles are `UILabel`.

Some one help me out here.

Screenshots.

[image: iPhone 4s]

[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or a xib?  Or are you doing this all in code?

Comment: @robmayoff I am using storyBoard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I find that trying to make sense of Auto Layout constraints in code (and using NSLayoutConstraint) to be quite confusing and difficult to understand. [VFL (Visual Format Language)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) is powerful but I would recommend if you are just starting out with Auto Layout then working in Storyboard or a XIB file may be easier (depends on your individual preference).

Since this is quite an involved topic I've put together [a sample project for you to reference on GitHub](https://github.com/derekleeapp/AutoLayoutAndAlignmentExample). The benefit of this approach is that there is literally no code - all of the configuration is done in the Storyboard (or can also be done in a XIB file). Highlights of the constraints I created are below however please reference the sample project for specific details:

- Background View (Purple) - Constraints pin the top, bottom, left and right sides to the edge of the parent view.
- Icon Container View (White) - Constraints pin the bottom, left and right sides; a height is also set which accommodates all of the icons.
- All image views have a width constraint and aspect ratio constraint (maintains equal width and height) and all labels are constrained to their appropriate image with the appropriate vertical constraint (top).
- The outside corner icons are all constrained only to their corner (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right). The center corners are constrained to be centered horizontally inside the view.

If you are just getting started with Auto Layout you may find [the following presentation I made](http://www.slideshare.net/DerekLeeBoire/2014-09-20-i-os-meetup-sept-auto-layout-for-posting) helpful in learning the basics.

Here are three screenshots from different simulators which show how the layout adjusts automatically depending on the screen size: iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus:

[image: iPhone 5s Example]

[image: iPhone 6 Example]

[image: iPhone 6 Plus Example]

Technically, landscape orientation is also supported by these constraints however the result may or may not fit your requirements. (I am unsure what orientations you are planning to support.)

Comment: I find the storyboard more confusing that writing them out in code (with some kind of category making them easier to read). I also get much more understanding by typing the code out myself. This is just my opinion though and I know some people prefer the storyboards and find them easier to use. This is a good answer if the user wants to take this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments Hodson. I agree that it is a matter of personal preference & it's great that we have the option to do either. In previous versions of Xcode there were certain constraint options that were not available through Storyboards and it required code to implement them, but with Xcode 6 I feel that many of these shortcomings have been resolved.

Comment: Warning in AutoLayoutAndAlignmentExample:- Layout attributes relative to the layout margin on iOS versions prior to 8.0 @DerekLee

Comment: @DerekLee currently only for portrait orientations but any tips to use this UI for landscape orientation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really want to write the code for your whole view as its not the best way for you to learn and plus I don't have the time right now. Instead, I will tell you the approach I usually take:

Create the view

```
UIView *myView = [UIView new];
```

Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Add view as subview

```
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Add the constraints

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];

[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

You need to add multiple constraints in order to layout the view exactly as you want in relation to the other views around it. Top, left (leading), right (trailing) and bottom.

I suggest either creating your own category in order to make writing the constraints quicker and easier to understand when reading it back. Here's one for example: [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)

You can also use constraints with a visual format but I often find this can be harder to get your head around.

More reading on the whole subject can be done [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement and their may be different ways to achieve. But if you ask in this particular case with three items as fixed then following may help:

- The buttons at the corners can have constraints with borders.
- All the labels can have constraints with their respective buttons to be same width and should be aligned horizontally centred with buttons.
- The buttons in centre and buttons at the borders should not have any dependencies with each other.
- The buttons in centre can have constraints with top and bottom of the container view.
- Buttons in centre should have constraints for horizontally centred with the container view.

You might need to add some more constraints, but based on the above suggestions it will work for any screen size.