# Separate Views for Portrait and Landscape using Autolayout in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

(iOS 8, Xcode 6.1, Objective-C, iPhone/iPad)

How can I create separate views for portrait and landscape views?

For example, I am trying to demonstrate some functionality within a Web view. For portrait orientation, I would like them stacked, as in Figure 1 below. When in landscape view, I would like them side-by-side, as shown in the Figure 2.

Any advice? tyvm :) Keith

[image: Figure 1. Desired portrait view]
[image: Figure 2. Desired landscape view]

Comment: My suggestion would be have two separate views. One for portrait and one for landscape. Then, just detect the orientation (and listen for orientation changes) and display the correct view.

Comment: creating constraints? but, I think setting a frame is better.. example just get the device width and height and then /2 and you can updated it when changes the orientation..

Comment: Are you more asking how to actually implement auto layout within the two separate views? If so, you can take a look at this answer I posted on a question about auto layout before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26507973/1813167

Comment: @Hudson: bleech. Separate controllers to duplicate content? Seems kinda 2004-ish. No, I would like one single view to present the webviews appropriately based on device orientation.

Comment: Select: Compact width | Regular Height from the bottom of you storyboard for Portrait

Select: Regular width | Compact Height from the bottom of you storyboard for Landscape

Answer (score 0):

xCode 6.1:

Select: Compact width | Regular Height from the bottom of you storyboard for Portrait

Select: Regular width | Compact Height from the bottom of you storyboard for Landscape

You don't have to create any view for Any:Width |  Any:Height

This how you can you size classes here.

[image] [image]